# In Perl, how to clone output to stdout and a log file in real time

Tags: perl, windows-console

I want to clone the output to the console as well as to a log file simultaneously. Here is my code snippet:

```
open STDOUT, ">>", "temp.txt" or die "";
system("echo This is a sample output..........");
```

But, here I only get output in the `temp.txt` and not on the console.
Can you suggest a solution? I am using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will output to `STDOUT` and `temp.txt`,

```
use Capture::Tiny::Extended 'tee';

tee(
  sub { 
    system("echo This is a sample output..........");
  },
  { stdout => "temp.txt" }
);
```